# Could not load file or assembly Telerik.OpenAccess

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, telerik-reporting, telerik-open-access

I added references to telerik dlls in the codeBut, when I am building the project I am receiving an error randomly.

Error1Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly'Telerik.OpenAccess, Version=2015.1.220.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342' or one of their dependencies. Can not find the file specified.

I am not using openaccess assembly at all. I have no idea why this keeps coming randomly. I am not even able to find the dll anywhere to add it to the project.

Kindly help me fix this issue.

Comment: Which telerik dlls did you add as reference to the project?

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me (and after searching around, for many others) this was due to dll files erroneously remaining in the bin folder, even after cleaning the solution. In my case the dlls were somehow left over while switching from one git branch (which included some dlls that depended on Telerik.Openaccess) to another.

I manually cleaned out my bin folder and rebuilt my solution and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is discussed in the Telerik forums: https://www.telerik.com/forums/unable-to-build-the-application-after-adding-telerik-references.

What you can do is to:

- delete the contents of the licenses.licx file and save it.
- delete any references to the Telerik.OpenAccess.dll in the project. If needed edit the solution file of the project in a text editor and remove the reference from it.
- Last but not least delete your VS and .NET cache - [Clean Up ASP.NET and Visual Studio Cache and Temp Files](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/knowledge-base/common-cleanup-asp-vs-cache-and-temp)